# How to call this.somefunction() on programmatically created iframe's onLoad?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have one angular service which creates iframe. Now, on onLoad of this iframe I want to call some function of same service.

```
private createIframe() {
  let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.onload = function() { this.somefunction();}
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  this.aAuthService.createLoginUrl('').then(function (url) {
       iframe.src = url;
  });
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

private somefunction() {...}
```

I am getting error saying "somefunction does not exist on  HTMLIframeElement".

How can we call somefunction() from onload while dynamically creating iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing:

```
iframe.onload = function() { this.somefunction();}
```

Now, `this`is not pointing to your Service class, but it's actually pointing to the anonymous function, so either you have to bind `this` to the anonymous function scope, so this.somefunction refers to the class method instead to an inframe specific property (that doesn't exist), or use a fat arrow function instead, since the fat arrow functions refer to the lexical scope instead of local function scope.

```
iframe.onload = () => this.somefunction()
```

That should do it.